# How can I listen to some tcp ports with libevent?

Tags: linux, gcc, libevent

I need to listen to some TCP ports with LibEvent.
How can I do this?
Should I create one application and in this apps create phtread for each TCP port or should I create one application for one port?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. While it is somewhat answerable, you probably didn't ask what you want to know. Have you looked at this websites FAQ or maybe http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use LibEvent it makes sense (well, it makes sense in any way) to use multiple threads to handle connections.